# Is this claim about equine anatomy true?

Tags: zoology, anatomy

While bumping through obscure corners of the Internet, I encountered the following image posted somewhere.

[image]

> The horse anus is a marvel of evolutionary biology.
>
> Like most mammals, rhythmic contractions of the bowels move the feces up to the end of the gut to be expelled.
>
> What sets the horse anus apart is the bafflingly complex autonomic contractive motion of 4 muscular rings which function like sphinctoral guillotine. As the feces is squeezed out, the rings expand and the
>   outermost ring is retracted into an interior skinfold resembling the human foreskin, leaving an interstital tissue fold to open air.
>
> The two inner rings then contract, and push apart, severing the horse feces cleanly, allowing to drop free as the outer ring folds back through the interstital flap, creating a intrinsic wiping motion with the fourth ring as it contracts back into the horses rectum.
>
> This advanced biological mechanism is so effective that many industrial companies have copied Nature's design for self-cleaning viscus liquid dispensers housed within complex machinery.

Quite interesting, but anyone who saw one, recognizes an imageboard post - probably the infamous 4chan, where each page bears the warning: "The stories and information posted here are artistic works of fiction and falsehood. Only a fool would take anything posted here as fact." Accordingly, I'm skeptical. So, a verification please?

Comment: Can you please quote them by posting their text as text and not as image. It is hard to read from this image. Also, images are not searcheable and poses trouble to visually impaired people. Also, if the text makes a number of claims, then which one exactly are you willing to question in this post?